# Angular throw an error 'uncaught object' on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

what am i doing wrong?

Go to fiddle page 
http://jsfiddle.net/C7gGb/1/

There is an error in console

```
Uncaught object angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:3555
forEach angular.js:300
loadModules angular.js:3521
createInjector angular.js:3461
doBootstrap angular.js:1282
bootstrap angular.js:1297
angularInit angular.js:1246
(anonymous function) angular.js:20126
trigger angular.js:2298
(anonymous function) angular.js:2562
forEach angular.js:300
eventHandler
```

Comment: there is a typo...it should be controller in line 3 in JS...

Comment: Fix the typo and include the JS in the right place and it will work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/C7gGb/3/

Comment: oops, sorry! still an error even in updated version

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add how you can track such errors in the future. Since I don't have enough reputation yet, I cannot post it is a comment so therefore I post it like this, although I am aware that it is not an answer to your original question.

These errors are in fact uncaught exceptions that are thrown by Angular. I got the exception message out of Chrome by selecting in the console that Chrome should pause on exceptions. See [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) for instructions on how to pause on exceptions.

Then, when the exception occurs again, a line like the following will be highlighted in the source code tab:

```
throw $injectorMinErr('modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}",
                  module, e.stack || e.message || e);
```

You can then view the exception message by going to the console and pasting 'e.stack || e.message || e' there.